# jQuery: trigger event when input changes

Tags: jquery

This is my [form](http://tinyurl.com/pt24nsn)

I have a textarea that counts the number of characters typed. This is called "Uw advertentietekst".
I have an input field that stores the number of characters. Called "Aantal karakters"
I have conditional logic on my gravityforms wich is `if the number of the inputfield is between 0 and 100 characters, show product input field. If the amount is between 101 and 200, show another product input field.`

This is my jQuery:

```
$('textarea').on("input", function(){ 

    $("inputfield").val($("textarea").val().length);

    $('inputfield').on("input", function(){ 

        // Gravityforms 

    });

});
```

The if/else for showing the product field is generated by Gravityforms.

The thing is. When I type my own amount in the input field (Aantal karakters), the productfield conditionally shows, yeeh! But when it's generated automatically, it does not. Any ideas?

Comment: have a look at the `change` event.

Comment: What if/else? Please post _all relevant_ code - I really don't like clicking on random tinyurl links - See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: try replacing the on('input') with something like on('input change keyup paste')

Comment: I don't know GravityForms, but I assume it's server side code. If it is, then it gets evaluated when showing the page, not when executing the javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try **change** event, e.g.:

```
$('textarea').change(function(){ 
   // your code
});
```

Comment: If I use change, it only updates whenever I click somewhere outside the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

May be like this

```
$('textarea').on('keydown paste blur click',function(){ 
   // your code
});
```